# Fatal error: Class 'PHPExcel_IOFactory' not found in phpExel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I used the code below and all PHPexcel library data are in the image below.

```
<?php
$inputFileName = './NIB.xlsx';
$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
?>
```

[image]

I want to read NIB.xlsx file and I have read this [help link](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/wiki/User%20Documentation%20Reading%20Spreadsheet%20Files).

However, when I run my PHP script, I received the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'PHPExcel_IOFactory' not found in phpExcel in untitled-2.php

Comment: Are you `including` the PHPExcel library anywhere in your code?

Comment: ya you r right. now my code is working...thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you forgot to include the PHPExcel file
Add this line at the beginning of your code

```
require 'PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
```

Dont forget to add the path of your folder,incase its in a different folder

Comment: this file is working in php but when i use it ajax called page it does not responce. and when i remove the "require 'PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php'; " it give me responce. now what should do?

Comment: now its solve thanks for asking and helping . its because of some HTML content repeated. :)

Comment: Welcome..Good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

I received this error as well, while trying some simple examples from the official documentation.  I am using PHPOffice installed with Composer.  The concept should be the same if installed locally.  Error is basically a path issue, i.e. the script not knowing where IOFactory can be found.  Here is the complete working solution I found.

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

$styleArray = [
    'font' => [
        'bold' => true,
    ],
    'alignment' => [
        'horizontal' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::HORIZONTAL_RIGHT,
    ],
    'borders' => [
        'top' => [
            'borderStyle' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Border::BORDER_THIN,
        ],
    ],
    'fill' => [
        'fillType' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID,
        'color' => [
            'argb' => 'FFA0A0A0',
        ]
    ],
];

$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello World !');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A3:m3')->applyFromArray($styleArray);


// Redirect output to a client's web browser (Xlsx)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats- officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="webstats.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$writer = PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
$writer->save('php://output');
exit;
```

I changed this line in online example from

```
$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
```

to this

```
$writer = PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
```

and the IO error was resolved

Comment: my answer is based on the example found here https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/recipes/

Comment: Using `PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter (...)` worked for me too